# Laravel - mixed content is preventing users from login into my site

Tags: laravel, vue.js

First of all, please know that I am new to Laravel + VueJS + Vuetify, ie. barely a few days old. I have a web application originally developed and setup by a remote developer, that works perfectly on my local development machine but when I pushed it to the staging site, I am getting the following error in the console.

> VM38:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://staging.mywebsite.com/' was loaded over HTTPS,but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://staging.mywebsite.com/api/v1/auth/check'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I have no idea what I need to change to make this work on both local, staging and production sites as the original remote developer is not much help and almost impossible to contact. Please provide as much detail as you can, eg. absolute path of the files that needed to be changed, etc... so I can do this myself.

Below are code snippets in config files that I assumed are used by the framework for this purpose.

**.env file**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_URL=http://localhost
...
...
APP_DOMAIN=localhost
APP_API="/api/v1"
MIX_APP_DOMAIN="${APP_DOMAIN}"
MIX_APP_API="${APP_API}"
```

**config/app.php**

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message says, your route `/api/v1/auth/check` is served over HTTP but your website is over HTTPS.

So, convert your route link to HTTPS. If the url is generated with a Laravel helper, check your `APP_URL` in your `.env` file and ensure that it starts with `https`.

Comment: Based on what I have posted above from my .env and config/app.php file, what exactly do I need to change but still allows me to work locally, ie. `http://localhost` and on the staging/production sites, ie. `https://`. Thanks.

Comment: I did and it broke my local development. We used Gitlab and I was wondering if the original developer used a separate config file when the application is built and deployed on Gitlab. is there a separate config file used by Gitlab CI/CD that is used when deploying to staging and production sites?

Comment: Don't change it in local, only on production. .env files are different for each environment. They are environmental files

Comment: What do you mean by "only on production"? Where would these production environment file be located? Sorry if this sound really newbie but I am one! :)

Comment: I mean your `.env` files should be separate in local and production servers/folders. This file should not be committed to code. So your local `.env` file may have `APP_URL=http://localhost` while your production `.env` file may have `APP_URL=https://staging.mywebsite.com`

Comment: OK. I think I understand what you are trying to tell me. So the .env file is ignored by .gitignore as its only used for my local development. So I would need to go to my server that holds the staging and production files and edit the .env files directly there. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: Thank you! I will try to get access to the servers and see if I can edit the .env file. Is this the only variable that you think is causing this mix content problem? There is nothing else in Laravel that might cause this issue? The staging site seems to be working fine except when its tries to call the API via a non-secure http:// instead of https://. Anyway, I will try it out and see if that work

Comment: That's definitely one issue, but not sure if that's the only one. If you post your code that generates the link, it will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your app was loaded in https, therefore you need to use https on your api calls

```
https://staging.mywebsite.com/api/v1/auth/check
```

Comment: That much I understood. How do I resolve this. I have attached snippets of what is in my .env and config/app.php files. What do I changed?

Comment: I did and it broke my local development. We used Gitlab and I was wondering if the original developer used a separate config file when the application is built and deployed on Gitlab. is there a separate config file used by Gitlab CI/CD that is used when deploying to staging and production sites?